# Securing REST API with Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a REST API for my Spring application. As there are resources which might not be accessed by everyone, I need a security layer.

Within this application I'm already using Spring Security (which works perfectly fine) for securing my web application.

I've added the following `http` configuration to my `spring-security.xml`:

```
<http pattern = "/api/**" use-expressions = "true" disable-url-rewriting = "true">
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

So I would assume that all request that are made to URLs starting with `api/` will be secured.

**Problem** is that I can access my secured methods without any authentications. But if I use a REST client to access it, I receive this error:

```
message: Full authentication is required to access this resource
description: This request requires HTTP authentication.
```

I have no idea how to proceed. What is the best way to secure a REST API using Spring Security?

Comment: How do you access your secured methods that you say you see them without authentication? Through browser? Are you already on a browser with a logged-in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Spring Security in your application, you, probably, already have an `<http>` section in one of your Spring config files. You can use this section to secure your REST API.

The `<http>` does not secure anything on its own. You have to add `<intercept-url>` rules inside it:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

Comment: But I'm using @PreAuthorize in my controller. So I thought that I don't need it. I don't use in the other `http` section.. Anyway, problem is, that authentication via browser works fine, but not with my REST client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tuto on the official site of Spring. It is a little more complicated :
[Official Spring Tuto](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/5/)

Comment: I don't use JavaConfig and additionally I have two security contexts (webapp and rest api).

Answer (score 0):

**Just use Spring Security.** In `<http>` tag add: `<security:intercept-url pattern="your url" access="hasAnyRole('Your_User_Role1', 'Your_User_Role2')" />`.
Or try use **annotations**. In your spring-config.xml enable security annotations: 
`<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>`
and in Controller add `@PreAuthorize` :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Your_User_Role1', 'Your_User_Role2')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/address_planing/load_employee_info")
```